# How can I refresh browser in silverlight 4 application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have an Silverlight 4 application, in log-in process I have some validations and data preparation, for any reason in each step if I get an exception, I want to stop my application and refresh the browser but I want save my exception message from my last session and then update my error text block in log-in screen and inform my user about exception message.how can I save my variable in session and then refresh browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On silverlight side you may use HtmlPage namespace ,

Beside this refreshing a page in silverlight is not a good practice,and shows your app. as if broken.Siverlight is a RIA. using benefits of this Rich platform is better I think.

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "_self");

 /* You may also add Query String to your URL as Bryant said,
 Uri myUri=new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.toString()+ "?Exception=True", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myUri, "_self");
*/
```

Hope helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just take the current url and append your error message to the query string and then use javascript to open the current page to that url. You can then get the query string from silverlight to get the error message.